# Fake purchasing of in-app item?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

There is a reward in an app which gives a user 1 in-app item for free if he completes a survey. Right now, I coded a `SharedPreference` entry which forcibly tells the app that the item had been purchased and never offers that item for purchase.

Is there maybe a better method? To tell Google Play that item had been rewarded and to give it for free to this specific user.

Comment: I don't think you can do that through the play store, you'll have to have your app manage it.  At least I don't see any mechanism to do so in the developer console.

Comment: @nasch Yes, the same here. But I guess someone will propose a better way if it exists.